# Display Image From Parse In Swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform, parse-ios-sdk

I am trying to display the image I have stored in Buddy For Parse into a UIImageView, however I keep getting this error:

> Could not cast value of type 'PFFileObject' (0x1045e0568) to 'NSString' (0x1041d75d8).
>   2019-04-13 18:15:09.869460-0500 PerfectLaptop[43839:3094232] Could not cast value of type 'PFFileObject' (0x1045e0568) to 'NSString' (0x1041d75d8).

I have already stored numerous strings into Parse, and am able to access them with no problems, and have stored the image I wanted to use also, however no matter what I try, I can't seem to get it to work. Many of the solutions I have found include casting the object as a `PFFile`, however this doesn't seem to exist anymore.

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "whichOneRecommended")
query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in
    if error == nil
    {
        if let returnedobjects = objects
        {
            for object in returnedobjects
            {

                if (object["whichOne"] as! String).contains("\(self.whichOneJoined)")
                {
                    self.laptopImage.image = UIImage(named: (object["laptopImage"]) as! String)



                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

While the image file is viewable and downloadable in parse, I can't seem to actually have it be displayed in the `imageview`, and i want the image view to change programmatically by running this function as I have with other parts of the object.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If it has solved your issue, it would be helpful if you could accept my answer. If not, let me know and I will try to help further.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing to note is that `PFFile` has been renamed to `PFFileObject`.

You are trying to pass `object["laptopImage"]` which is a value of type `Any` to `UIImage(named:)` which can't be done because that function expects a `String`.

Firstly you need to create a constant of type `PFFileObject`:

```swift
let file = object["laptopImage"] as? PFFileObject
```

And then download the file data, create a UIImage from the `PFFileObject` and assign the image to the `UIImageView`:

```swift
file.getDataInBackground { (imageData: Data?, error: Error?) in
    if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    } else if let imageData = imageData {
        let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
        self.laptopImage.image = image
    }
}
```

Details on this can be found in the [section on files in the iOS Guide](https://docs.parseplatform.org/ios/guide/#files).

Answer (score 0):

guard let imageString = message,
let imageURL = URL(string: imageString) else { return }

```
    do {
let imageData = try Data(contentsOf: imageURL)
    image.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
    } catch {

    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).